# Entry point after GLTF entity animation ends on aframe 0.9.*

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have a basic aframe app showing a GLTF model with built in animation. Is it possible to have an entry point to do something when built in animation has ended?

code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <a-scene >

        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="animated-asset" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicolocarpignoli/nicolocarpignoli.github.io/master/ar-playground/models/CesiumMan.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity gltf-model="#animated-asset" scale="2"></a-entity>

        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animations won't work with vanilla a-frame, so I'm [assuming](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/gltf-model.html#using-animations) you're using [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) for the animations.

---

According to the [docs](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders#animation-events), you can use two events to determine when an animation has finished:

- `animation-loop` - when a single cycle has finished
- `animation-finished` - when all loops are finished

so you can create a component (here `cycle-count`):

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#animated-asset" animation-mixer cycle-count>
```

which will wait for the `animation-loop` event, and let you know when the animation cycle has finished:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cycle-count', {
  init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener('animation-loop', e => {
          // cycle finished - do whatever you need
      })
  }
})
```

fiddle logging cycles [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vjgc32rb/2/).

Comment: Glad i could help, if you don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)

Comment: is there any way to specify which animation clip has finished?